# How to change different layout of table or div in responsive screen

Tags: css, responsive

[image]

I have created a table, but the problem is the layout is completely different in mobile compared to desktop.

I can adjust the CSS of the mobile screen but the structure is completely different in mobile, so I think it cannot be resolved by doing this.

To solve this, if I make two different layouts, one for mobile and one for desktop, then it would make the task difficult to code everything two times.

Please suggest the best way to do this.

Comment: You probally will need a concept similar like this:
http://allthingssmitty.com/2016/10/03/responsive-table-layout/ In that concept the styling is done for each tr. So for multiplay rows it will be a little bit more difficult and it probally will require some scripting to pull that off.

Comment: okay but if i create two different table 1 for desktop and i for mobile, so it will be good way or not or not ! can you advice me???